# How to fix a dynamic link editor error in py2app?

Tags: python, loader, py2app, dyld

I am having trouble with `py2app`. I keep getting the following error code after running **python setupSimpleGUI.py py2app** in terminal:

> TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'

I have tried various main.py programs (many of which are simple tkinter based programs) and have written my `setup.py` files exactly as they are written on all of the `py2app` tutorials. I know that the error has something to do with mac dynamic link editor, but that's it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240052/py2app-typeerror-dyld-find-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-loader

Comment: Gnomesss! Mine was here first :(