# How do you use py2app with matplotlib?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, cx-freeze, py2app

I have made an application that uses matplotlib to display a plot in a tkinter window. I am wanting to create a standalone app, and I have been trying to use both py2app and cx_freez, but both encounter a problem when I try to compile the program.  I believe the issue has something to do with matplotlib because when I deliberately disable the imports for that module and then compile, the app will launch and only fail until it encounters code that requires matplotlib. I am unsure if I am excluding something from my setup.py file.  I have tried using some of the code [from here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib) with little success.

When I run my setup.py in Terminal:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    app=["Calculator.py"],
    setup_requires=["py2app"]
)
```

This is the error I get in the Terminal after it is 'done' compiling:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    setup_requires=["py2app"]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 959, in run_normal
    self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1214, in create_binaries
    platfiles = mm.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 105, in run
    mm.run_file(fn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 84, in run_file
    self.scan_node(m)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 110, in scan_node
    m = self.load_file(filename, caller=node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 93, in load_file
    newname = self.locate(name, loader=caller)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 23, in locate
    newname = super(FilteredMachOGraph, self).locate(filename, loader)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 49, in locate
    loader=loader.filename)
TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'
```

When I try to run the app, I get this error in the console:

```
2015-07-21 22:17:55.588 Calculator[85122:57708133] Calculator Error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/camon/Documents/Python Apps/Compiler/dist/Calculator.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 81, in <module>
     _run()
   File "/Users/camon/Documents/Python Apps/Compiler/dist/Calculator.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 62, in _run
     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
   File "/Users/camon/Documents/Python Apps/Compiler/dist/Calculator.app/Contents/Resources/Calculator.py", line 9, in <module>
     from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
   File "/Users/camon/Documents/Python Apps/Compiler/dist/Calculator.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.4/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 7, in <module>
     from six.moves import tkinter_filedialog as FileDialog
   File "six.pyc", line 90, in __get__
   File "six.pyc", line 113, in _resolve
   File "six.pyc", line 80, in _import_module
 ImportError: No module named 'tkinter.filedialog'
```

After looking at the errors, I looks like some modules or other stuff is not being added during the compiling process. What do I need to add to my setup.py file? Or is it something I need to address with matplotlib?

ALSO... here is a list of all the modules in my program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from math import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib import style
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random
```

EDIT:

I found out that matplotlib needed `tkinter.filedialog` and `tkinter.messagebox` imported. Once I did that, the app launched and appeared to function. However, I still get the same error in the Terminal when I compile it. Is the setup.py still missing elements?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240052/py2app-typeerror-dyld-find-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-loader