# py2app error when making standalone program with wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, py2app

I'm making a small GUI application with Python 3.4.3 and wxPython.
I used py2app and firstly got this error:

```
TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'
```

This was fixed by changing `loader` to `loader_path` in MachOGraph.py (it's explained [here](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/137/py2app-problems-using-enthought-python)) and I could create an app. However, I can't open it. The error I got was:

```
2015/10/07 23:58:45.749 GUIApp[38168]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015/10/07 23:58:45.749 GUIApp[38168]:   File "/Users/S_Python/dist/GUIv2.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 355, in <module>
2015/10/07 23:58:45.749 GUIApp[38168]:     _run()
2015/10/07 23:58:45.749 GUIApp[38168]:   File "/Users/S_Python/dist/GUIv2.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 336, in _run
2015/10/07 23:58:45.750 GUIApp[38168]:     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
2015/10/07 23:58:45.750 GUIApp[38168]:   File "/Users/S_Python/dist/GUIv2.app/Contents/Resources/GUIv2.py", line 2, in <module>
2015/10/07 23:58:45.750 GUIApp[38168]:     import wx
2015/10/07 23:58:45.751 GUIApp[38168]:   File "wx/__init__.pyc", line 17, in <module>
2015/10/07 23:58:45.756 GUIApp[38168]:   File "wx/core.pyc", line 6, in <module>
2015/10/07 23:58:45.756 GUIApp[38168]:   File "wx/_core.pyc", line 14, in <module>
2015/10/07 23:58:45.757 GUIApp[38168]:   File "wx/_core.pyc", line 10, in __load
2015/10/07 23:58:45.757 GUIApp[38168]: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/S_Python/dist/GUIApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/wx/_core.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: @loader_path/libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.3.0.dylib
2015/10/07 23:58:45.757 GUIApp[38168]:   Referenced from: /Users/S_Python/dist/GUIApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/wx/_core.so
2015/10/07 23:58:45.757 GUIApp[38168]:   Reason: image not found
```

Comment: You can find the answer in [py2app TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240052/py2app-typeerror-dyld-find-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-loader)