# PIL ImageTK not loading image in py2app application bundle

Tags: python-3.x, osx-lion, python-imaging-library, py2app

I'm testing out an app that I've made which, amongst other things, loads a couple of .png images when opened. The images are displayed correctly on my Mac (10.7.5) and my mother's (10.8.5); however when my sister opens it on hers (10.9.5) the images don't load. All other functionality is otherwise intact. I should note that on my Mac and my mother's, I installed Python 3.4 and many of the packages that the app uses, including the PIL package, whereas my sister has none of these. The app was build using the command:

```
python3.4 setup.py py2app
```

Images are imported in the code with:

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "images/pic.png")
```

Setup file for py2app is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['myapp.py']
DATA_FILES = [('', ['images'])]

OPTIONS = {'iconfile': 'myapp.icns', 'packages': ['PIL']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

My guess is that it's an issue with PIL, it just doesn't seem to want to play nicely with py2app. The reason I think it's PIL is because after running the command to build my app I get the following error message in Terminal.

```
Modules not found (conditional imports):
* Image (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/recipes/PIL/prescript.py)
```

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions or direction.

Comment: I am getting the same error and I will post here if i find anything

Comment: if you are installing Image from the Pillow library the way you should install it is  `from PIL import Image`. Your sister's computer most likely has a more recent version of python so this is hence the way to install it, any other way would throw an error

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a python package that requires other packages to be installed, you can use the `install_requires` keyword within setup [see docs](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html).  This has the additional benefit of installing the package(s) when the user runs pip install py2app.  In your case I would use install_requires=['pillow'] and pip will automagically grab pillow during the installation process.